# Using Generators to iterate in AngularJS using ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iterator, angularjs-ng-repeat, generator

ng-repeat in AngularJS seems to not work with generator functions. It works as expected inside the controller, but when used inside HTML expressions, the generator seems to have been already terminated. Could you folks explain to an angular noob what sorcery is going on here?

```
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.items = function*() {
    //console.log(1);
    yield 1;
    //console.log(2);
    yield 2;
    return null;
  }();
  //console.log($scope.items);
  //console.log($scope.items.next().value);
  //console.log($scope.items.next().value);
}


<div ng-app ng-controller="Main">
  <h2>{{items.next()}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    Hi {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ouae9wm/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for generator function to return a generator that can be iterated it should be called with `items()`, `items` is just a function. And this still won't work in this case.

[Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable) (and generators are the ones) are meant to be iterated with special treatment in legacy JS loops, this involves monitoring  `generator.next().done` status to end the loop. [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop serves to treat iterables transparently.

Generators don't have `length` property and don't necessarily have to be finite. `ngRepeat` iterates through object keys or [array-likes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.3/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L447%5C) in `for` loop by using `length` property, it isn't aware of iterables/generators.

If the generator is finite, it should be converted to array before it will be fed  to `ngRepeat`.